# Need to push all JSON into an array from AJAX, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, dom

Here's the code:

```
var newFeeds = []; // ** GLOBAL **

$(document.body).click(function() {

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://mysite.com/feed.php",
            success:  function (data) {
                        $(newFeeds).push(data);
                        alert(newFeeds.length);
                        },
            error: function(error){
                      alert('Error: ' + error);
                    },
            dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

I can get the data from the server. All is ok, but the array never fills up. 
But strangely `newFeeds.length` returns 0! Why? 
I need to take the arrived data and push it into an array for later use.

Comment: and not forgetting of course that `newFeeds` won't be filled until _after_ the async call has completed

Comment: So you guys gonna help him, or pass over a beer and a bag of chips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(newFeeds).push(data)
```

supposed to be

```
newFeeds.push(data)
```

**newFeeds** is an array that you have declared.

```
var newFeeds = [];
```

But in the callback you are wrapping it like a `jQuery Object`

```
$(newFeeds)
```

Comment: ok, after correcting that (my bad, forgot to undo all my tries) it still won't sum up. I get 3 results in the json. I'd expect to get 6 on the second click, but it remains 3 for some reason(?)

Comment: @Ted are you sure you're giving the callback a chance to complete before checking the array length (per comment above on the question) ?

Comment: How does `data` look like ?

Comment: @Alnitak.. I think he is checking for the array length inside the callback

Comment: @Sushanth-- [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Do you see 3 other objects when you click the 2nd time.. Check in the `Network` tab of your browser

Comment: looks to me like you'll get _one_ element in `newData` for each AJAX call, where that element will itself be an array containing "n" nested objects.  The `push` call doesn't "flatten" the received array.

Comment: Everything seems ok in the `Network` tab @Sushanth--... I keep getting the 3 objects... Wait a minute! I am using the same data each time in my php file (just static data), could it be hashing the array? therefore not pushing what's already inside?

Comment: Nopes. Sorry. I thought this might have been the problem but I see that a new data coming simply overwrites the old array....

Comment: @Ted. Glad to have helped :)